# How to send data from angular 6 to node server?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, server, angular6

I'm trying to send datas from angular 6 to nodeserver.I have used http.post to pass data & I haven't used Auth.Token function & all. But still I'm getting an error in the browser like

My component.ts:

```
 function(){
     return this.http.post('http://localhost/postdata', data, httpOptions).subscribe(result => {
       console.log(result);
     }, error => console.error('There was an error: ',error.message));

  }
```

My Server:

```
 app.post('/postdata', function (req, res) {
   console.log("hi there");
 });


"TypeError: this.getAuthToken is not a function
at Object.push../src/app/_network/HttpInterceptor.ts.InterceptedHttp.addAuthHeaders (HttpInterceptor.ts:45)
at Object.push../src/app/_network/HttpInterceptor.ts.InterceptedHttp.intercept (HttpInterceptor.ts:31)
at InterceptedHttp.value [as intercept] (Logger.class.ts:7)
at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1137)
at HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:1748)
at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1137)
at HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:1788)
at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:974)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:60)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:50)"
```

Im totally new to angular 6. Can anybody please help how to resolve this?

Comment: What port are you running node on? 
Also, your component.ts function looks weird, as it has no name. Try putting it inside the constructor instead and it might work (although it's not how you should design your app)

Comment: Your code seems to be correct from what i can see.
It seems to be your HttpInterceptor which is trying to get an authToken. (Maybe to authenticate with your sever?)

What is inside your "httpOptions" ?

Comment: @Michel Ferreira Ribeiro thanks for answering. I have commented some files under network & its gone. Now Iam able to post the data.